# How to pip install Holopy in Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install holopy in google colab, but very stuck right now.

I need to install this specific package, and seems like I need to install holopy in colab first.

```
from holopy.core.metadata import get_spacing, data_grid, copy_metadata
```

I've been trying to install using

`%pip install hologram-python` or `%pip install holopy`

`!pip install hologram-python` or `!pip install holopy`

but none of them includes the package I'm looking for.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run every one of the following commands in a new block

1. Download or clone the latest version of HoloPy from Git Hub at https://github.com/manoharan-lab/holopy.
   `!git clone https://github.com/manoharan-lab/holopy`
2. cd to that cloned directory
   `cd /content/holopy`
3. Pip installs all the requirements
   `!pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. now run `python setup.py develop`

If everything above goes all right, check if `holopy` has been installed correctly by the following command

```
from holopy import check_display
check_display()
```

You should see an image like this  and you should be able to change the square to a circle or diamond by using the left/right arrow keys.

[image]
Hope it helps.